# Need a Query ( u can use cross join there)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Here table name is `cricket` and column is `team`:

```
team
----
IND
BAN
PAK
SRI
```

I need a query which can show the result like this:(see down table)

```
team_a  team_b
------  ------
IND      BAN
IND      PAK
IND      SRI
BAN      PAK
BAN      SRI
PAK      SRI
```

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?

Comment: the title says everything you need. just do it.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen , yes, but I got this "ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data" as an error.

Answer (score 1):

You need a CROSS JOIN with a self join on the table.

```
select a.team as team_a
       , b.team as team_b
from cricket a
     cross join cricket b
where a.team != b.team 
/
```

The trick is the WHERE clause, which prevents joining the same team, because obviously IND can't play IND.

If you don't want to generate reciprocal pairs of matches then change the WHERE criteria to use less than instead of equality:

```
select a.team as team_a
       , b.team as team_b
from cricket a
     cross join cricket b
where a.team < b.team 
/
```

Here is [a SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/105d7/5).

Comment: No, It won't happening, It is giving me 12 rows, while I need only 6 rows.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were trying to generate 'home and away' matches. What is your rule for deciding whether a team is TEAM_A or TEAM_B?

Comment: Don't know, actually it was an interview question, BTW thank you, I have got the answer.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful please consider upvoting and/or accepting it. Accepted answers improve the quality of StackOverflow for other Seekers.

Comment: @Ranjan : Interesting.. I remember. Someone asked me the same question once, few years back though... I can recall, I rejected their offer :-)

Comment: @KaushikNayak - why not? Using CROSS JOIN seems like a reasonable interview question. Don't you like cricket?

Comment: @APC : of course I liked the question... and the game - It's like a religion here in India.I rejected the offer for some other reason.... :-)

Comment: probably too easy interview question for KN

Comment: @KaushikNayak - ok, u rejected their offer, and they reject me for that question ;)

Comment: @APC - Ohh, I didn't know about that, ok I am upvoting it.

Comment: select t1.c1 as team_A, t2.c1 as team_B
from
(
select t.c1 , 
ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by 1 order by t.rowid) as r_num
from pr_test t
) t1,
(
select t.c1 , 
ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by 1 order by t.rowid) as r_num
from pr_test t
) t2
where t1.c1 <> t2.c1
and t1.r_num < t2.r_num